# Add custom forms in checkout process in commerce kickstart

Tags: commerce

In Commerce Kickstart checkout process Checkout,Review order,Payment,Checkout complete are sections. I want to add one more section like Availability. How should I add?

Answer (score 0):

Use [hook_form_alter](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) to add field(s) or section on any form in drupal.

For more information go through the documentation of this hook.